# How can we perform performance testing of API if I am using using Rest Assured?

Tags: rest, performance-testing, rest-assured, web-api-testing

How can we perform performance testing of API if I am using using Rest Assured?

I am planning to use Rest Assured for API testing but also want the same tests to carryout the performance testing. Is there a way we can achieve the performance testing by integrating another tool/framework with Rest Assured?

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to run your RestAssured requests in a multithreaded manner you can consider using a micro-benchmark library like [`jmh`](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)

However a better idea would be converting your Rest Assured tests into normal HTTP-based load test, this way you will get HTTP protocol related metrics

1. Choose a load testing tool which provides HTTP recording capabilities via proxy. You can check out [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use/) article for some tools listed and compared
2. Configure RestAssured to use the load testing tool as the [proxy](https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.2.0/io/restassured/RestAssured.html#proxy)
3. Run your RestAssured test
4. Load testing tool should capture the requests which you should be able to replay with multiple virtual users